# why is $(document).height() different from $(document.body).height()?

Tags: jquery, document

I have been googling for a while, but still could not find why
is `$(document).height()` different from `$(document.body).height()`?

What's more, could anyone tell me the corresponding relation between the height methods
in jQuery and the raw JavaScript ones?

For example, `$(document).height()` is equivalent to `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`.

Comment: try body{margin: 0; padding: 0;} and then check heights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `<body>` element in your HTML is just another block element (much like a `<div>`), and as any block element, it can have dimensional styling (`margin`, `padding`, `width`, `height`, etc).

Considering that, the "size" of the `<body>` element does not need to correspond directly to the size of the `document` object (which corresponds to your whole HTML document as rendered, as a whole). One good reason is that the `<body>` element is also inside the `<html>` element, which is **also** a block element, and can have its own respective dimensionals.

If your `<html>` element, for example, had `padding:10px`, then your `<body>` element will definitely differ in effective size to the whole `document` entirely.

Now, don't get me wrong: `document` and `document.body` **can** have the exact same size (try checking StackOverflow's for example), but you have to understand that `<body>` is just another HTML block you can manipulate via CSS.

Comment: hi, Ilagan, per your answer, you think if we reset the browser   standard css(html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}), then we will get   same heights, including clientHeight, offsetHeight and scrollHeight?  
BTW: I have done some tests, the results were not like that.

Comment: If you reset back to `html, body { margin:0; padding:0; }`, **and** make sure your `width`s and `height`s are set properly you should. It's not just about margins and paddings. Make sure you're not *overriding* your reset rules somewhere down some other stylesheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the body has a standard margin.
For the second part, I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: yup, I do think a standard margin is one of the reasons that makes those two differ from each other, but there should be some other reason(s) out there. Anyway, thx for your help.